# How to trigger a method instead of directly accessing an attribute in Go?

Tags: go

```
type User struct {
  FullName string
  FirstName string
  LastName string
}

func (u *User) FullName() string {
  return u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName
}
```

I want this line of code: `user.FullName` to call the FullName method instead of directly accessing the FullName attribute. Is there a way to do this in Go? And this example will throw an error like this: `type User has both field and method named FullName`

Example use case:

The first and last name are persisted in a db but the full name is not. If I will just access the full name field of the User struct, it will not correctly return the full name of the user.

Another example is when serializing it to json, the full name will be blank. Unless I do something like:

```
func (u *User) SetFullName() string {
  u.FullName = u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName
}

user.SetFullName()

// serialize to json and return an http response...
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to do it automatically.

Comment: Why do you have a `FullName` field at all?

Comment: @user2357112 I updated my question.

Comment: "I want this line of code: user.FullName to call...": There is no "I want" in Go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot do what you're asking originally, but to solve your issue with marshalling your json, you could implement a custom `MarshalJSON` method like so:

```
type User struct {
    FullName  string `json:"-"`
    FirstName string `json:"first_name"`
    LastName  string `json:"last_name"`
}

func (u *User) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    type Alias User
    return json.Marshal(&struct {
        FullName string `json:"full_name"`
        *Alias
    }{
        FullName: fmt.Sprintf("%s %s", u.FirstName, u.LastName),
        Alias:    (*Alias)(u),
    })
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/M-CVqzTT7B

You could remove `FullName` from the `User` struct if you wanted to, and just leave it in the `MarshalJSON`.. I added the `json:"-"` because you will have 2 `full_name` fields if you didn't ignore the one.

Comment: Great! Thanks! And if I want to access the full name, I can just add a GetFullName() method in the User struct. And also use GetFullName() method in the MarshalJSON method to avoid duplication of generating the full name - https://play.golang.org/p/Png5-orZ_Y